# Holes in gaussian mixture plot

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I'm trying to plot a gaussian mixture model using matlab. I'm using the following code/data:

```
p = [0.048544095760874664 , 0.23086205172287944 , 0.43286598287228106 ,0.1825503345829704 , 0.10517753506099443];

meanVectors(:,1) = [1.3564375381318807 , 5.93145751073734];
meanVectors(:,2) = [3.047518052924292 , 3.0165339699001463];
meanVectors(:,3) = [7.002335595122265 , 6.02432823594635];
meanVectors(:,4) = [6.990841095715846 , 3.5056707068971438];
meanVectors(:,5) = [6.878912868397179 , 1.1054191293515965];

covarianceMatrices(:,:,1) = [1.3075839191466305 0.07843065902827488; 0.07843065902827488 0.3167448334937619];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,2) = [0.642914957488056 0.15638677636129855; 0.15638677636129852 0.382240356677974];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,3) = [0.8216051423486987 0.15225179380145448; 0.15225179380145445 0.37030472711188295];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,4) = [1.064002437166605 0.11798234162403692; 0.11798234162403692 0.2687495955430368];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,5) = [0.6445011493286044 0.15295220981440236; 0.1529522098144023 0.5231676196736254];

obj = gmdistribution(meanVectors', covarianceMatrices, p);

figure(1);
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]), [-10 10], [-10 10]);

figure(2);
ezsurf(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]), [-10 10], [-10 10]);
```

But the resulting surface appears to be really "spiky". Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is ploting the function
This piece of code is much slower, but it works for me

```
p = [0.048544095760874664 , 0.23086205172287944 , 0.43286598287228106 ,0.1825503345829704 , 0.10517753506099443];

meanVectors(:,1) = [1.3564375381318807 , 5.93145751073734];
meanVectors(:,2) = [3.047518052924292 , 3.0165339699001463];
meanVectors(:,3) = [7.002335595122265 , 6.02432823594635];
meanVectors(:,4) = [6.990841095715846 , 3.5056707068971438];
meanVectors(:,5) = [6.878912868397179 , 1.1054191293515965];

covarianceMatrices(:,:,1) = [1.3075839191466305 0.07843065902827488; 0.07843065902827488 0.3167448334937619];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,2) = [0.642914957488056 0.15638677636129855; 0.15638677636129852 0.382240356677974];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,3) = [0.8216051423486987 0.15225179380145448; 0.15225179380145445 0.37030472711188295];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,4) = [1.064002437166605 0.11798234162403692; 0.11798234162403692 0.2687495955430368];
covarianceMatrices(:,:,5) = [0.6445011493286044 0.15295220981440236; 0.1529522098144023 0.5231676196736254];

obj = gmdistribution(meanVectors', covarianceMatrices, p);

x = -10:.2:10; y = x; n=length(x); a=zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n, for j = 1:n, a(i,j) = pdf(obj,[x(i) y(j)]); end, end;
surf(x,y,a,'FaceColor','interp','EdgeColor','none','FaceLighting','phong')
```

Comment: simply increasing gridsize won't do in certain cases. The algorithm you supplied, though slower, works every time instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the default grid size, which is 60. Set a higher number and you will get the expected result:

```
figure(1);
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]), [-10 10], [-10 10],300);

figure(2);
ezsurf(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]), [-10 10], [-10 10],300);
```

Comment: It seems to be a different problem. When I run the OP the code, in my matlab version 2012b, at some points the plot is empty. It is like ezsurf is not ploting properly the return of pdf (even if you increase the number of mesh points). Did it work for you the OP code?

Comment: This solves the problem for ezsurf, but increasing the grid size for ezcontour() has the side effect of making weaker components deasappear from the plot.

Comment: @sebas: given a gridsize of 100, the surface plot was reasonably good.

Comment: @AlexGaspare: the weaker components disappear because the smaller grid finds a higher maximum. The lines are evenly spaced between min and max, I don't know any possibility to influence this behaviour.

Comment: @Daniel: could you suggest an alternative to ezcontour?